# If you came earlier, I could go there. (Past vs Subjunctive mood)

Tags: subjunctives

If you came earlier, I could go there.

The sentence could be interpreted below.

1. You didn't come earlier and I could not go there (past)
2. It looks like you are not going to come earlier but if you come earlier, I can go there. (Subjuctive mood)

Which one is correct?

Comment: The second is the natural way to interpret it.  You're correct, though, that there is another interpretation - but it is not quite what you have for #1 - it would be "1. You didn't come earlier, so now I cannot go there."

Comment: (Your interpretation would be written as "If you came earlier, I could have gone there.")

Comment: Equivalently, "If you had come earlier, I could have gone there."

Comment: That, I would say, is why the second interpretation is favored.  The first one just doesn't come up often in usage.  Maybe the second person arrived on a horse, but now the horse is tired and needs to rest, so the speaker can't go... but even then we might just rephrase it - with something like "I would be able to go" for example.